# No launch.json file when trying to run debug in VS code

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am trying to get my debug working in VS code for my Ruby code but the instructions do not make sense for me. On the github page it tells me to:

> Go to the debugger view of VS Code and hit the gear icon. Choose Ruby or Ruby Debugger from the prompt window, then you'll get the sample launch config in `.vscode/launch.json`.

But when I open that debugger view in VS code there is no gear icon. I have spent days searching online but I cannot find a solution. I have no auto generated `launch.json` so I do not know what to put in it even if I create my own.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is the launch.json file in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67495792/where-is-the-launch-json-file-in-vs-code)