# Where is the 'launch.json' file in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

The *launch.json* file should be inside the *.vscode* folder, but it is not present there.

How can I get this file so that I can modify the configurations?

Answer (score 46):

As described in the [Launch Configurations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations) section of the Visual Studio Code documentation:

> VS Code keeps debugging configuration information in a `launch.json`
> file located in a `.vscode` folder in your workspace (project root
> folder) or in your [user settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_global-launch-configuration) or [workspace settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces#_workspace-launch-configurations).
>
> To create a `launch.json` file, **click the create a launch.json** file link
> in the Run start view.

As of Visual Studio Code 1.56:

[image: Visual Studio Code screenshot for create launch.json file link]

Once that's created, it should now be available under your workspace's *.vscode* folder.

[image: VS Code screenshot of File Explorer with launch.json file]

Comment: Note the details of the docs quote in the answer. The launch configs may be defined in the global `settings.json` or your workspace settings (`foo.code-workspace`). In this case, you won't have a `launch.json`, and trying to open it from the command palette (ctrl+shift+p) will take you to the file with the existing launch configs. [In this bug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/14388), VSCode isn't picking up launch configs defined outside `launch.json`.

Answer (score 3):

Click on the debug side bar to open the debugging options. Then either the cog icon at the top, or the create a launch.json file link below the big blue button. If the launch.json file is present, it will open it otherwise it will generate one.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: if you try to create an empty one (or one with an invalid content), trying to get to that file through the "Create a launch.json file" would not do anything.

See [issue 133327](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/133327).

That will be fixed with VSCode 1.61 (Sept. 2021): at least, that existing file will be opened when  you click on  "Create a `launch.json` file".

Answer (score 0):

The `lacuch.json` resides inside the `.vscode` folder inside your project's root directory. If it doesn't exist, you can create it from the debug tab which is mentioned in another answer. There is another place where you will be able to create the `launch.json` file. Select some file to debug (e.g.: test.py), now from the dropdown select "Debug File". This will also create a `launch.json` file inside the `.vscode` folder under your project's root directory.

[image: launch.json]