# I have an error with executing c++ code on MacBook. I am using Visual Studio code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have a problem with executing the c++ code. It seems like I didn't compile this, but I still don't know what to do.

[image: Error message]

[image: launch.json]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is the launch.json file in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67495792/where-is-the-launch-json-file-in-vs-code)

Comment: Please read [here on why not to post code, data or errors as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) (and even less so as link to an image on an external service).

Comment: Looks like its looking for the launch.json in your helloworld folder instead of your .vscode folder.